# Lost partition in Win 10, cant assign a drive letter

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, diskpart

Yesterday, after a restart, I discovered out that drive D is missing. 
I can see the partition in Disk Management console but there is no information about it.

I tried to assign a drive letter to it, but it warned me: "Operation failed cause console is not up to date."

I checked out `DiskPart`, it shows the partition with "list partition" 
but not available with "list volume" command,

[image: screenSHOT]

Note: I have deliberately left that 80 GB unallocated.

Comment: You seem to be familiar with `diskpart`. Did you try to assign a drive letter to the partition using `diskpart` instead of MMC?

Comment: Did you try to create a new volume on this partition?

Answer (score 0):

you could also try downloading a free partition software such as Minitools Partition Wizard v9 - it will bring up an interface much like the windows one - try right clicking on the partition and assigning a letter.

Might work, and if so save you starting from scratch, if not, then at least you know its not just the windows disk manager.

You could also then try recovering the partition from Minitools, using the partition recovery wizard - again itmight work and you can get the whole partition back - and you may be able to browse the results and see the files you need to recover.

Then you can decide whether to try recovery software. Both EASUS and Minitools do very similar Partition and Recovery software, and the free versions are pretty useful before it starts to cost.  I used EASUS today and it let me save an xml of the partition status after the scan, which was very useful as the scan took about 8 hours and I didnt want to lose it and start again if the power went out!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to recover your lost data back or recover your lost partition*** then use **easus data recovery software**.

If you don't want to waste your time using those recovery methods then simply delete the pariotion and create a new ntfs partition and assign any letter you want.

Partition tools for windows

1.windows disk management

2.easus data partitioning software

..........etc.

If above methods didn't worked for you
Use a **linux live gparted partitioning os using usb / live cd boot**.(or any linux distro which have **gparted/fdisk/cfdisk/gdisk**....etc.)